# Setting number of items for cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport

Tags: angular, datasource, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

I have found a number of tutorials for using the `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport`, but there is one thing missing from every single tutorial I have found so far: how do I tell the viewport how many items are in my list?

I have implemented this using a `BehaviorSubject` for the datastream according to [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-infinite-scroll) and a few others, but I can't figure out any way to get it to load anything past the first 10 items that I initialize it with. The `collectionViewer` doesn't seem to care that I have more items than what I initialized it with, and neither it nor the `BehaviorSubject` have any members where I might be able to specify the length.

This seems like an extremely basic thing to be able to do (unless you're going for infinite scroll, but even then I don't see how you notify the viewport that there are more items yet to come), but aside from a few tutorials that tell me to initialize a 10,000 item array upfront (doesn't that defeat the purpose of loading items dynamically?), nobody seems to care about scrolling past the end of the previously fetched items.

What gives?